# From a UX perspective, what keycloak can and can’t do?

Tags: usability, user-centered-design

From a UX perspective, what keycloak can and can’t do?

I was asked to design a signup page and follow and use our existing security tasks that a user must finish before they are allowed to log in. Which is the two-step verification. The new dev is asking me what keycloak can and can’t do.
Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: It’s more helpful to read the keycloak documentation for an answer I guess.